# Web service return type: String, Object or Map

Tags: java, web-services, return-type

Our organization is running a web service written in Java (Now using AXIS. Being converted to JAX-WS). Most of the methods are returning fields retrieved from database as delimited string (delimiter is '|'). In the client side (Now the client is provided only by us. May be in the future, the web service will be open to others) we retrieve string and convert them back to fields.

Now there is a request to convert the string to either:

1. A java bean class which has method names indicating the names of the fields.
2. A String array
3. A Map with key names and values

We are very concerned about the performance (As we are using the same server which runs the web service inside the organization), as it is going to be used by thousands of people.

1. Hence which will be better in the above three methods and why ? **OR**
2. Should we stick to the delimited string and let the client do the
   rest (As we are doing now)?

Comment: IMHO, your java bean class, sent as a `json` response would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Well PSV (Pipe Delimited Value) which you are using is of high performance but it lacks structuring capabilities that of an XML or JSON.

Consider the following.

1. If your Web Service is consumed by other Applications with high processing capabilities convert the retrieved values from database to an XML and send it as a response. This could be a typical SOAP response.
2. If your Web Service is consumed by Front End code of a Web Application (Preferably using javascript) you are better off using JSON.

I have worked with SOAP based web services which handles millions of transactions and find it very reliable. And consider using AXIS2 instead of JAX-WS to increase performance.